# Check registry key and value for exists

Tags: c#, registry

I would like to check in two functions if the registry SubKey and the registry value are existing.
Unfortunately, I always get errors. For example NullReferenceException: The object reference was not set to an object instance.

So far I have tried a function which checks if the registry SubKey is present.
See code example:
It should return true if the SubKey exists and create the SubKey if it does not exist.
But I don't know how to read the value if it is bool, int or a string.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

```cs
public static string RegPath = @"Software\" + Application.ProductName + @"\";
public static bool CheckIfKeyExists(string SubKeyName)
{
    var reg = RegPath;

    var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(reg + SubKeyName);
    if (key != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(reg + SubKeyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the GetValue() method returns a value which is not NULL to avoid assuming that you get a not null value.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetValue` methods gives you back an `object` that you can cast or convert the appropriate type, e.g.:

```
var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(reg + SubKeyName);
if (key != null)
{
    foreach(string valueName in key.GetValueNames())
    {
        object rawValue = key.GetValue(valueName);
        if (rawValue != null)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(rawValue);
            //...
        }
    }
}
```